# How to automatically update vue component when data changed without refresh page

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have fetched data by using axios. But it seems like vue component doesn’t update after click event and when the data changed. So I have to refresh the page in order to update data on the page. Do you have any simple way to solve this problem?

This is the code from template.

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Latest Posts</h1>
    <div class="create-post">
        <label for="create-post">Add new post...</label>
        <input type="text" id="create-post" v-model="text" placeholder="Create a post">
        <button v-on:click="createPost">Post!</button>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <p class="error" v-if="error">{{ error }}</p>

    <div class="posts-container">
      <div class="post" v-for="(post, index) in posts" v-bind:item="post" v-bind:index="index" v-bind:key="post._id">
        {{`${post.createdAt.getDate()}/${post.createdAt.getMonth()}/${post.createdAt.getFullYear()}`}}
        <p class="text" id="example">{{post.text}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>
```

This is the code from script

```
<script>
import PostService from '../PostService';

export default {
  name: 'PostComponent',
  data() {
    return {
      posts: [],
      error: '',
      text: ''
    }
  },
    computed: {
      postText: function() {
        return this.post.text
      }
    },
    watch: {

    },
  async created() {
    try {
      this.posts = await PostService.getPosts();
      console.log(this.$el.textContent) 
    } catch(err) {
      this.error = err.message;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async createPost() {
      await PostService.insertPost(this.text);
      this.post = await PostService.getPosts();
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this line:
    `this.post = await PostService.getPosts();`
should be 
    `this.posts = await PostService.getPosts();` Here's a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/srdecny/pen/zYYvboj?editors=0001) link. If that doesn't fix your issue, ensure the `PostService` returns correct objects.

Comment: Oh thank you so much. That was a stupid mistake from me. But I was just wondering why I didn't get any error message that 'post' is not defined.  Anyway thank you so much!